# Chain functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-validator

Is there a way to chain functions in JavaScript so when last function in chain is called we take into consideration all function in chain that was specified.
Basically what I am trying to do is the same thing [express-validator](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator) 
does:
Something like this:

```
check('password').passwordValidator().optional();
```

I want to be able to call

```
check('password').passwordValidator();
```

and

```
check('password').passwordValidator().optional();
```

Comment: Your functions need to return an object that has a method(s) that will be called on it.  You normally need a function like `value()` or `end()` to indicate the last function in the chain if you want a single output value because the function doesn't know if you will chain another function.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So you're looking for a sort of [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)? You can do that like this:

```
class Foo {
  _passwordValidator = false;
  _optional = false;

  passwordValidator() {
    this._passwordValidator = true;
    return this;
  }
  optional() {
    this._optional = true;
    return this;
  }

  doThing() {
    if (this._optional) { /* ... */ }
    if (this._passwordValidator) { /* ... */ }
  }
}

const foo = new Foo().passwordValidator().optional();

foo.doThing();
```

Edit: to more directly answer your question, there is no way to wait to do something until the current chain of method calls is done; you have to call a method like `doThing()` in the example to signal that you actually want to do the thing now.

Comment: I believe `passwordValidator` and `optional` would both need to return `this` in order to be chainable, correct?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnOerter yes, of course, I feel dumb now. Blz, you do have to `return this` from each of the methods that you want to be part of the builder.

Answer (score 9):

I ended up using what @coolreader18 suggested.
That was exactly what I was looking for.

```
function func(val) {
    this._optional = false;
    this._check = false;
    
    const doStaff = (message = 'Doing staff') => {
        console.log(message);
        return;
    };


    return {
        check: function(n) {
            this._check = true;
            return this;
        },
        optional: function(n) {
            this._check = false;
            this._optional = true;
            return this;
        },
        exec: function() {
            if (this._check) doStaff();
            if (this._optional) doStaff('Maybe not');
        }
    }
}

func().check().optional().exec();
```

Comment: does return `self` does the same job? instead of returning `this` from methods

Answer (score 5):

```
var Obj = {
  result: 0,
  addNumber: function(a, b) {
    this.result = a + b;
    return this;
  },

  multiplyNumber: function(a) {
    this.result = this.result * a;
    return this;
  },
 
  divideNumber: function(a) {
    this.result = this.result / a;
    return this;
  }
}

Obj.addNumber(10, 20).multiplyNumber(10).divideNumber(10);
```

link => https://medium.com/technofunnel/javascript-function-chaining-8b2fbef76f7f

Answer (score 2):

Calling a chained method of `express-validator` returns a middleware function, and as functions can have properties you can call a method on that returned function, which returns a new function with methods and so on. Chaining functions is quite easy:

```
 const chain = (pairs, fn = el => el) => {
   for(const [key, method] of pairs)
     fn[key] = (...opt) => chain(pairs, method(fn)(...opt));
   return fn;
};

const math = chain([
  ["add", prev => a => b => prev(b) + a],
  ["mul", prev => a => b => prev(b) * a]
]);

console.log(
  (math.add(5).mul(3).add(3))(5)
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is inspierd by React setState:

```js
function pipe/*<U>*/(val/*: U*/) {
  return {
    case: function (condition/*: boolean*/, value/*: U | ((prop: U) => U)*/) {
      if (condition) {
        if (value instanceof Function) {
          return pipe(value(val));
        } else {
          return pipe(value);
        }
      } else {
        return pipe(val);
      }
    },
    valueOf: function () {
      return val;
    },
  };
}

  const result = pipe(2)
      .case(false, 3)
      .case(true, (current) => current + 2)
      .case(false, 4)
      .valueOf();
      
console.log(result) // 4
```