# How can I make functions like 'hello().world()'?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to figure out how to make the functions that are like:

`hello().world()` where `hello()` and `hello().world()` return two different things.

But I don't how to describe so am unable to find it via searching.
The node js module moment is the only place I've seen this used and it uses it as so:

`moment(), moment().format(), moment().hours()` etc.

If anyone could explain or direct me to somewhere what explains it that'd be great. 
Thanks.

Comment: Return an object from the first function. That object should have a method named by the second function.

Comment: `let hello = function() { return { world: function() { } } }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chain functions in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54137801/chain-functions-in-javascript)

Comment: OP said __"don't know how to describe"__  -- the downvotes are not helpful -- PLEASE stop driving newcomers away from the site.  One downvote negated -- Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below. Return an object from the hello function which has the `world` method.

```js
function hello() {
    return {
        world: () => {
            console.log("Hi");
        }
    }
}

hello().world()
```